# Adding Text and Images in the same row using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to put text right of an image using the bootstrap classes. I am fairly new to using bootstrap. I used the float class but the image just gets put under the text. I want to have it so the img tag is under the text tag in the code. I also do not want to use any css in this project. I know it is impractical but I am curious if you can make the text and Images side by side with the img tag under the text tag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225505/how-to-make-text-wrap-around-image-with-bootstrap-4-without-float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the img on the left but under the text in the code you have to invert order:

```
<div class="row">
 <div style="padding:0" class="col-6 order-2">Text</div>
 <div style="padding:0" class="col-6 order-1">Image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work but it leaves a wide whitespace between the img and the text, thank you for your feedback:)

Comment: If you want no space you have to add style="padding:0" in your col div (i uptated the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Text right of an image using the bootstrap classes, but with the img tag under the text tag in the code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 p-0 order-2">Text</div>
    <div class="col-6 p-0 order-1">Image</div>
</div>
```