# How to make image aligned left and content right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

**With "bootstrap": "^4.3.1"**
I try to make **image aligned left** and **content which floats** image from the **right** and would be visible below of the image ( without empty space under image ).
I works ok to in class `single_forum_image_left_aligned` to leave `float: left;` property:

```css
  .single_forum_image_left_aligned_wrapper {
    border: 3px dotted red;
    align-items:start;
  }

  .single_forum_image_left_aligned {
    display: flex;
    justify-self: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: 460px;
    max-height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="single_forum_image_left_aligned_wrapper">
  <a class="a_link" >
    <img class="single_forum_image_left_aligned" src="imagepath/general-business.jpeg?dt=1606807690"
         alt="Mount Everest is found in which mountain range?">
  </a>
    
  <p class="card-text " style="align-items:start">
    Lorem <strong>ipsum dolor sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis <strong>nostrud exercitation</strong> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint  occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

But that does not seems good decision for me.

Are there some better solution ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your requirement?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49225729/6890636) ?

Comment: something like that https://prnt.sc/vtezp2

Comment: Thanks for this link : looks I need to use float-left anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write single line of code of this type of view in *Bootstrap-v4+*
In *Bootstrap-v4* there is predefined class **.float-left** for **float: left;** property.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="d-block clearfix bg-light p-3 shadow">
        <a class="float-left mr-3">
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals" class="rounded">
        </a>
        <p>
          Lorem <strong>ipsum dolor sit</strong> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis <strong>nostrud exercitation</strong> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint  occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reading flexbox docs I get recommended to get rid of methods float: left/right and in the biggest cases I do it with success. But not in this